# tmux: unbind C-[ as a prefix

Tags: tmux

I have a fairly straight forward `.tmux.conf` file which does nothing more but to define a couple of options, such as `history-limit`. I have not added any custom key bindings yet.

I find it extremely annoying that I cannot unbind `C-[` as a prefix in tmux. Here is what I mean:

```
$ uname -a
Linux stan-inspiron 3.2.0-24-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 21 16:52:17 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ tmux
[0] 0:~*         "stan-inspiron" 10:05 12-Jun-12

  % vim
```

Whilst inside `vim`, when I go to insert mode and then use `C-[0` to escape insert mode and move to the first character on the line, tmux grabs the key first and complains:

```
Window not found: :0 **
```

I tried all sorts of things in my `.tmux.conf`, but nothing works. I thought it might be a terminal or shell issue, but confirmed same behaviour on a configless machine using Bash and [Gnome] Terminal.

So the question really is, how do I unbind the `C-[` key from tmux?

** I have `base-index 1` set.

Answer (score 0):

I've just finished my [.tmux.conf](https://github.com/StanAngeloff/dotfiles/commit/b2b2db01ec011177b01929c4c57ffe67061eadc1#diff-3) file and the issue is gone. I can't say which option turned it off, but I am glad it's gone for good. Thank you all for reading/participating.